# Set the order of lighbox items

Tags: jquery, lightbox2

This is for the jQuery plugin [Lightbox2](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Is there a way to set the order of items when the lightbox is open?

I have a layout with every item absolutely positioned, and, I think, because they are out of DOM order they cycle through the lightbox in a seemingly random order. That "random" order is consistent on every page load.

On a whim, I tried tabindex but that didn't work.